# Is there a way to initialize a variable with a value based on the template type

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I have a template class. The class has a private member variable which I like to have preset to a certain value which differs for each template type.

I was thinking about different constructors for different types, but since the constructor has no parameters I have no idea how to do it.

Is it possible anyway ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a specialization on the type, the easiest form is:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct make {
  static int value() {
    return -1; // default
  }
};

template <>
struct make<int> {
  static int value() {
    return 1; 
  }
};

template <>
struct make<double> {
  static int value() {
    return 2; 
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo {
  const int val;
  foo() : val(make<T>::value()) {}
};

int main() {
  std::cout << foo<int>().val << ", " << foo<double>().val << "\n";
}
```

But you could also arrange it as an overload:

```
#include <iostream>

int value(void *) {
  return -1; // default
}

int value(double *) {
  return 2;
}

int value (int *) {
  return 1;
}

template <typename T>
struct foo {
  const int val;
  foo() : val(value(static_cast<T*>(nullptr))) {}
};

int main() {
  std::cout << foo<int>().val << ", " << foo<double>().val << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [traits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traits_class) template and specialize it with the value. something like:

```
template <typename T, typename Traits = MyTraits<T> >
class MyClass {
public:
  int Foo ()
  {
   return Traits::Value;
  }
};

template <>
class MyTraits<SomeClass>
{
public:
   static int Value = 1;
};

template <>
class MyTraits<AnotherClass>
{
public:
   static int Value = 2;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the mapping from template parameters to values into a helper class, giving you something like this:

```
template<typename T> struct foo_helper;
template<> struct foo_helper<int>   { static int getValue() {return 1; } };
template<> struct foo_helper<float> { static int getValue() {return 2; } };
....


template<typename T> class foo 
{
   int m;
   foo():m(foo_helper<T>::getValue()){}

};
```